# Why am I not receiving email notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, email

I have my email notification settings set to notify me every three hours, but there have been times when I didn't get notified for months.

I haven't been receiving any email notifications. The questions I read similar to this did not address my concern. I've also checked my email inbox. I've also checked my settings. It says it would notify me every three hours.

Comment: What kind of notifications are you expecting? There doesn't seem to be that much activity on your questions, so a months-long gap would seem natural. No? Can you point to a specific event that you weren't notified about?

Comment: It was some time ago.  It was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208938/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-uiactivity-mail-error-unrecognized-selector-sent

Comment: I *think* E-Mail notifications are supposed to trigger only on answers, not comments, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's find.  I can check the website for comments if I have an urgent question.  For some reason I'm getting notifications from the meta stackoverflow site.

Comment: You should be able to get email notifications for comments, too, @Pekka. In fact, *anything* that goes to your inbox. See settings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current). Note that I haven't tested this personally, and have absolutely no idea why anyone would ever want this. Maybe someone who gets fewer than 50 inbox items here per-day. :-)